# gulp watch не хочет выполнять функции в квадратных скобках

Tags: gulp, gulp-sass, gulp-watch

Решил попробовать настроить gulp, но возникла проблема с выполнением 'browser-sync','sass' до 'watch'
По отдельности через консоль все работает

Вот код:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
sass = require('gulp-sass'),
browserSync = require('browser-sync');

gulp.task('sass', function(){
return gulp.src('app/sass/**/*.sass')
.pipe(sass())

.pipe(gulp.dest('app/css'))
.pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}))

});


gulp.task('browser-sync',function(){
browserSync({
    server: {
        baseDir: 'app'
    },
    notify: false
});
})


gulp.task('watch', ['sass','browser-  sync'], function() {
gulp.watch('app/sass/**/*.sass',     gulp.parallel('sass'));
});
```

Ошибка:

```
Last login: Thu Jan 31 23:10:55 on ttys000
mbp-andrej:gulp andrejpersin$ gulp watch
assert.js:350
throw err;
^
AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Task function must be specified
at Gulp.set [as _setTask] (/Users/andrejpersin/Desktop/gulp/node_modules/undertaker/lib/set-task.js:10:3)
at Gulp.task (/Users/andrejpersin/Desktop/gulp/node_modules/undertaker/lib/task.js:13:8)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/andrejpersin/Desktop/gulp/gulpfile.js:25:6)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
```

[image: не работают функции в квадратных скобках]

Comment: День добрый. Приложите пожалуйста стектрейс ошибки текстом ^_^

Comment: @Suvitruf, добрый день! Если я Вас правильно понял, то приложил:)

Comment: Я так понимаю, gulp у вас v4? Попробуйте ради интереса откатиться до v3. Ошибка останется?

Comment: @Suvitruf, спасибо, ошибка исчезла! Еще к Вам есть вопрос, если не затруднит, это нормально что, чтобы применилось изменение в sass и отобразилось на странице нужно нажать ctrl+S или обновление страницы должно происходить в live и автоматически отлавливать изменения в sass и применять их?

Comment: Нужно конфиг смотреть. Я, когда на react.js пишу, то хот релоад работает для стилей. И лучше это отдельным вопросом задать.

Comment: @Suvitruf Благодарю за помощь:)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый ^_^

Answer (score 1):

1. Можно откатиться к v3.
2. Насколько я понял в [v4 поменяли сигнатуру метода](https://fettblog.eu/gulp-4-parallel-and-series/): вместо `gulp.task(name, deps, func)` нужно писать `gulp.task(name, gulp.{series|parallel}(deps, func))`.

Answer (score 0):

Исправьте на:

```
 gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch(
      [....],
      gulp.parallel('sass')
```